# .setAdapter doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

The ListView is empty. The Logcat haven't an error. The application can read the data from the website. I checked it with the "Log.i("String", readLine.toString());" command.

```
String gamehost = "https://example.com";

private SharedPreferences speicher;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_worldhighscore);
    speicher = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Data", 0);
    editor = speicher.edit();

    String userid = speicher.getString("userid", null);


    ArrayList<String> strArray;
    strArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> stradapt;
    String quellcodee = null;
    URL urle = null;

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewuser);
    try {
        urle = new URL(gamehost + "/highscoreread.php");
        String readLine = null;
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(urle.openStream ()));
        while ((readLine = buffReader.readLine ()) != null) {
            strArray.add(readLine);
            Log.e("Data", readLine.toString());
        }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    stradapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Worldhighscore.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strArray);
    listView.setAdapter(stradapt);
    Log.e("Datas", strArray.toString());
}
```

> Logcat:
>   I/Data: 1305957942849692 - 18
>   I/Data: 1587261998061410 - 10
>   I/Data: 88030 - 4
>   I/Datas: [1305957942849692 - 18, 1587261998061410 - 10, 88030 - 4]

The R.layout.activity_worldhighscore:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listviewuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />
```

Edit: The code is changed.

Comment: Where do you place all this code? inside `onCreate` ?

Comment: Yes all of this code placed in onCreate

Comment: What is the issue you have ? null pointer ? Please show us the logcat error logs

Comment: I don't have any error in the logcat. The strArray is "[1449692 - 18, 61410 - 10, 88030 - 4]"

Comment: Your adapter is wrong...

Comment: first you cannot have network calls on main thread (unless you changed the policy) or you cannot update UI from worker thread so issues in both ways

Comment: Can you post the whole Worldhighscore activity code?

Comment: The BufferedReader work and the strArray != ""

Comment: Use AsyncTask for try-catch part.

Comment: Post also the `activity_worldhighscore.xml` layout

Comment: I have change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Use This

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List arr;
    int resource;
    Context context;
    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, List arr) {
        super(context, resource, arr);
        this.arr=arr;
        this.resource=resource;
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter, parent, false);
        TextView param1=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.param1);
        TextView param2=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.param2);
        final ArrayList<Class.MyOBJECT> data=(ArrayList<Class.MyOBJECT>)arr;
        param1.setText(data.get(position).param1);
        param2.setText(data.get(position).param2);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

...

```
Adapter adapter=new Adapter(this,R.layout..,arr);
ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and also next approach if you want to use default adapter

put this

```
stradapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strArray);
```

instead of

```
stradapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Worldhighscore.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strArray);
```

Comment: That's a custom adapter, he chose to use the default `ArrayAdapter`, according to official documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews what he did is valid

Comment: Which part of the answer was the solution to the question? the `Worldhighscore.this` -> `this` part or the custom adapter?

Comment: The custom adapter

Comment: @pleft i answered 2 approach .